System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Vue Project
I've vue project.
when i run project following message shows.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: D:\Vue Projects\Rifah\riphah_cms\src\server
Now listening on: https://localhost:8071
Now listening on: http://localhost:8070
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

but when i hit  url https://localhost:8071 or http://localhost:8070
it start loading and give following exception.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection:
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)

i am using oracle db which i've checked through telnet is ok.
Any suggestion.
Startup.cs as
namespace Ucp.Server
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var config = WebApp.Configuration.Get<Ucp.Server.AppConfig>();
        
        services.AddHttpClient<ITurnitinService, TurnitinService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.ithenticate.com/rpc");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        });

        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardLimit = 2;
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.122"));
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("117.20.21.108"));
            options.ForwardedForHeaderName = "OrignialIP";
        });

        services.Configure<AppConfig>(WebApp.Configuration);
        services.Configure<Ucp.Service.Config>(WebApp.Configuration.GetSection("service"));
        services.Configure<Ucp.Service.TokenProviderConfig>(WebApp.Configuration.GetSection("service:tokenProvider"));
        services.Configure<Ucp.Data.Config>(WebApp.Configuration.GetSection("data"));
        services.Configure<Ucp.Server.Config>(WebApp.Configuration.GetSection("server"));

        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.MimeTypes = new[]
            {
                "text/plain",
                "text/css",
                "application/javascript",
                "text/html",
                "application/xml",
                "text/xml",
                "application/json",
                "text/json",
                "image/svg+xml"
            };
        });

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddDetection();

        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
            new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

        services.ConfigureAuthentication(config.Service.TokenProvider, new string[] { "admin" });
        services.ConfigureMvc(config.Server.AntiForgery);

        services.AddDbContext<OracleContext>(options =>
        {
            string assemblyName = typeof(Ucp.Data.Config).GetAssemblyName();
            options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseOracle(config.Data.ConnectionString, s => s.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName));
        });

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                // Add other supported cultures here
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider());
        });

        var container = new Container(c =>
        {
            var registry = new Registry();
            registry.IncludeRegistry<Ucp.Common.ContainerRegistry>();
            registry.IncludeRegistry<Ucp.Data.ContainerRegistry>();
            registry.IncludeRegistry<Ucp.Service.ContainerRegistry>();
            registry.IncludeRegistry<Ucp.Server.ContainerRegistry>();
            c.AddRegistry(registry);
            c.Populate(services);
        });

        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        AppConfig config = WebApp.Configuration.Get<Ucp.Server.AppConfig>();
        IConfigurationSection logging = WebApp.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");

        if (logging.GetSection("Debug").Exists())
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (logging.GetSection("Console").Exists())
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(logging.GetSection("Console"));

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions()
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true,
                ProjectPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\ui")
            });
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseMiddleware<NoCacheMiddleware>();

        string webRoot = new DirectoryInfo(config.Server.Webroot).FullName;

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(webRoot),
            OnPrepareResponse = (content) =>
            {
                var cultureService = content.Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CultureService>();
                cultureService.EnsureCookie(content.Context);
            }
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<NoCacheMiddleware>();
        app.UseAntiforgeryMiddleware(config.Server.AntiForgery.ClientName);

        var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseHistoryModeMiddleware(webRoot, config.Server.Areas);

        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            using (var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContextBase>())
            {
                ICryptoService crypto = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICryptoService>();
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                dbContext.EnsureSeedData(crypto);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
    enter namespace Ucp.Server
{
    public class WebApp
    {
        internal static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(root)
            .AddUcp()
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(root)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            //.UseUrls("http://172.19.30.19:5000")
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
}

some days before it work fine and now without any changes when I run it give above error.
using node 10
